# Remote connect to SQL server - trusted connection, windows credentials

Tags: c#, sql-server

Sorry for the confusing name, I did not know of better one. There is a network with SQL 2005 server. I am provided with the windows account information to this computer so I can use remote desktop or map its drives. The SQL uses trusted connection. I am thinking whether I can connect remotely only to the SQL server? Thanks

Comment: I believe that this question is better suited for ServerFault.com...

Comment: Can you be more precise? Where there is exact problem? You are asking if you can connect to SQL server if you know server's credentials?

Answer (score 0):

*This is based on my experience with SQL Server, but may not be entirely complete in scope.*

SQL Server Manager will let you connect to the server instance with windows credentials, but to access the database tables you will need to create a **login** within SQL Server. Using SQL Server Manager, you can do this under the Security folder of the hierarchy of objects in the left column.

Next you will need to create a database (if one doesn't already exist that you are interested in using) and in that database's Security folder, create a **user** that corresponds to the login. When doing this you will also need to assign the permissions of the user (select, insert, delete, etc.).

Once that is complete, you can access the server anywhere on the network with the appropriate credentials, but you will need to make sure that there are no blocked ports, etc. from a network perspective.

In C# the statement to create a new connection looks like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("user id = username; " +
    "password = secret; " +
    "server = servername\sqlexpress; " +
    "database = databasename; " +
    "connection timeout = 30");
```

Hope that helps.